# analysis is not showing on OBIEE12c?

Tags: obiee

After uploading RPD, when I'm trying to create report nothing in UI is showing except report job and action, why it's happening like that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't happen after a simple RPD upload since the RPD doesn't control permissions and you clearly lost permissions.
You must have used a BAR file or done something to the security.